# drupal feed shows image urls in a link, not as src

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-feeds

I've mapped fields in excel spreadsheet (saved as csv) to those in a custom content type. Feeds are acting as expecting and generating nodes for me. But in spreadsheet I have the url of where the images are (I'm using MAMP, BTW). when I look at content source after import, I see this:

```
<div>
<span class="file>
<img class="file-icon" alt="" title="image/jpeg"   src="/modules/file/icons/image-x-generic.png"> 
<a href="[the url to image]" type="image/jpg; length="53059">[the file name]       </a>
</span>
</div>
```

So an image icon shows and a file name that is a link, but no image. Do I have my feed misconfigured, or what's going on?

J

Comment: You should give an example of what is spitting out... For example what are one of the broken links?

Comment: wow, you're fast. My code didn't make it up. Try it now. Thanks.

Comment: I figured this out myself. I created a new feeds importer and changed my image field to use the image widget instead of the Media file upload. I then tried the import again and it worked. I went back and changed the widget back to Media file upload, and it worked again. Not sure what was going on, but it had something to do with my importer.